# Readonly file system error / Unable to repair because volume is mounted

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount

I am new to Ubuntu, just install it on a machine running only 18.04 as OS on it. Worked fine for a few days but then all of a sudden it would just crash starting to output on the screen stuff like "Error writing file to disk" and "System is read-only", etc.

If I force restart the machine it starts normally, everything works for a while and then it crashes in that exact same way again.

I assumed that there might be a disk error so I went to `Disks` and clicked "Check Filesystem..." on all partitions. It would say no error until I reached the partition where the Ubuntu itself is installed. It is 15GB Ext5 partition but when I click the check on it, I get this:

> Error unmounting filesystem. Error unmounting /dev/sda2: target is
>   busy (udisks-error-quark, 14)

It makes sense since it is running at that very moment. However, I would assume that this is where the problem is. So if it is, how can I check and repair it? If it is not, has anyone else encountered something like this before and any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: Try running the same check from a live disk. Get your install media, boot from it, choose try Ubuntu and when you get to the desktop you should be able to check your 15GB partition

Comment: Great idea, the check passed successfully though and there was nothing to repair. I would assume my problem is something else then...